# PHP mysql fatal error Call to a member function fetch_assoc()

Tags: php, mysql

```
$szukaj_slowo = 'SELECT * FROM slowa WHERE slowo='.$slowo.'';
$wyslij_zapytanie = $connect->query($szukaj_slowo);
$pobierz_wartosc = $wyslij_zapytanie->fetch_assoc();
$szukaj_slowo_wynik = $pobierz_wartosc['slowo'];
    $connect->close(); 
    if( $szukaj_slowo_wynik == NULL || $szukaj_slowo_wynik == "" )
    {
        Header('Location: index.php');
    }
```

I take $slowo from form, but if $slowo is empty then i got a fatal error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\error_spr\wyszukaj.php on line 16
```

Comment: can you show what link is line 16?

Comment: $pobierz_wartosc = $wyslij_zapytanie->fetch_assoc();

Comment: you could use a while loop that would be better

Comment: Can you give me example?

Comment: @Vento i have posted a answer look at it and try that exact code

Comment: Ahh, the most asked PHP question ever. See the little white box at the top of the website? Use it.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen hahahaha :)